# Как проверить на этапе компиляции, что переданная в шаблон структура содержит в себе поле с определенным именем?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++17

Как проверить на этапе компиляции, что переданная в шаблон структура содержит в себе поле с определенным именем?

```
template <class T>
void foo(T a) {
  //как проверить что a имеет поле id
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**В C++20 и новее:**

Если хотите менять поведение в зависимости от наличия поля, то так:

```
if constexpr (requires {a.id;})
    ...
else
    ...
```

Если хотите ошибку, если поля нет, то так:

```
template <class T>
void foo(T a)
requires requires {a.id;}
{
    
}
```

Набор требований можно вынести в `concept`, чтобы потом применять в нескольких местах.

---

**В C++17:**

Проверить наличие поля:

```
template <typename T, typename = void> struct HasId : std::false_type {};
template <typename T> struct HasId<T, decltype(void(std::declval<T>().id))> : std::true_type {};
```

```
if constexpr (HasId<T>::value)
```

Отключить функцию, если поля нет:

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<HasId<T>::value, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
void foo(T a)
{

}
```

Comment: А есть способ сделать это в с++17?

Comment: @DenverToha Есть, дописал. В следующий раз, если версия языка не последняя, пишите сразу в вопросе.